# Stand-alone Flash projector doesn't take relative paths

Tags: flash, paths

I'm a Flash developer. I developed a Flash app which I want to distribute on all platforms. I recently installed Ubuntu and I'm using the Adobe Flash Player 10 to generate a stand-alone linux projector from my .swf file.

However, the generated projector seems to have problems dealing with relative paths. The app needs to load a lot of content dynamically from the disk (images, sound files). Normally, I use relative path names such as

```
./myfolder/
```

to tell my app where to find those files. This ceases to work with the stand-alone player. The app can't find the files specified this way. It will find the files if I specify them in an absolute fashion such as

```
/home/myuser/Desktop/myapp/myfolder/
```

But this is out of the question for something that needs to be distributed.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a syntax for relative paths I'm not aware of? The projector seems to think it's being executed in the path

```
file:///myapp.swf
```

that doesn't sound right. Is there a way to tell an executable in which base-directory it should be executed?

Is there a way around it? For example, launching the universal Flash player and loading the swf manually seems to work. Can I create a shortcut for this? On Windows I could create a shortcut to something like

```
flashplayer.exe myapp.swf
```

Is there an equivalent in Linux?

In general: any ideas for workarounds?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards